# ATmega168 versions for low power applications

Tags: atmega, low-power, atmel, attiny

I am interested in using an ATmega168 for a simple application, which has however very strict power limitations. As a result, the important thing for me is to find the version with the least power consumption. I checked several versions' datasheets, and this is what I found:

1. [ATmega168](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48_88_168_megaAVR-Data-Sheet-40002074.pdf): Active-250uA | Power Down-0.1uA
2. [ATmega168P](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48P_88P_168P-DS40002065A.pdf): Active-300uA | Power Down-0.1uA
3. [ATmega168PA](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061A.pdf): Active-200uA | Power Down-0.1uA
4. [ATmega168PB](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001909A.pdf): Active-350uA | Power Down-0.23uA
5. Bonus: [ATTiny24A](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATTINY24A): Active-210uA | Power Down-0.1uA

I expected that the "P" in the uC's name would mean lower power, which apparently is not the case(?). Apart from that though, I am very confused with the 168PB version, which mentions in the datasheet about the utilization of PicoPower Technology, but is the worst in terms of power consumption. Also, the fact that ATTiny consumes more than the ATmega168PA, really makes me think why one would pick ATTiny.

I would really appreciate it if you could give me some info if the above facts are right or I am overlooking something, and recommendations about which version I should choose after all. Also any info on the naming of the uC's would be welcome.

Comment: P means Picopower.  ATTiny is good choice when fewer IO  pins are needed and space used is important.  I'd go with the 168PA version, unless your code needs more flash/SRAM/EEPROM storage, then I'd go with 328P.  In all cases, you can turn off unused internal functions (such as ADC) to save more power, or run at slower clock rates. https://www.gammon.com.au/power for more. 16K flash, 8 bit architecture = 168. 32k flash, 8 bit = 328. B versions have a few more features, read the datasheet from microchip.com for more complete description.

Comment: Thank you for the information @CrossRoads. How can it be explained however that 168P consumes more power than the plain 168?

Comment: Make sure the operating conditions are the same  - especially clock rate - in these datasheet calculations. If the B grade is faster, and its power spec is at a faster clock, that would explain a lot.

Comment: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48_88_168_megaAVR-Data-Sheet-40002074.pdf   http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48P_88P_168P-DS40002065A.pdf
 http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-9223-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega48PA-ATmega88PA-ATmega168PA_Datasheet.pdf  Measured at different clock rates in Active mode.